# VBA: Method "Move" of object "Sheets" failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a simple module in VBA that works fine when saved it as a macro but when I saved the same as Add-In and run, it behaves strange.
It gives Error: Method "Move" of object "Sheets" failed
and then open sheets from file number 1 (x=1 in the code).

Thank you all for help. I have not tried it with another system to check security issue in my MS Excel but I have not locked code or sheet thru password.

Code:

```
Sub opensheets()
    Dim openfiles
    Dim x As Integer
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    openfiles = Application.GetOpenFilename _
    (FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files (*.xls;*.xlsx),*.xls;*.xlsx", _
    MultiSelect:=True, Title:="Select Excel files!")

    If TypeName(openfiles) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "You need to select atleast one file"
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If

    x = 1
    While x <= UBound(openfiles)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=openfiles(x)
        Sheets().Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets _
          (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        x = x + 1
    Wend
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you wanting to move all sheets from the opened workbook to the current workbook? You need to be explicit about the source workbook and destination workbook in the code, when writing code. As of now, it doesn't look clean.

Comment: The fact that it works as a macro but not an add-in is strange. When you run it as a macro, is it still in a module or is it in a worksheet or workbook object? Have you tried activating the sheet or assigning the workbook to a workbook variable?

Comment: Hi Lopsided, Code works fine but I am also surprised that why it gives error when saved as Add-In when it works fine as a macro. May be I am making sort of silly mistake. I am saving it as a macro in macro enable workbook while using it as a macro.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to take all worksheets from another book and move them to the end of your current workbook (the one that includes the code), then this worked for me:

```
...
While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=openfiles(x))
    wb.Sheets().Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets _
      (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    x = x + 1
Wend
...
```

If you are looking for something else, please clarify your question.

Comment: The code above works fine as a macro but when saved as Add-In it gives error. It would be great if someone can save it as Add-In and check if error still occurs.

Comment: In that case, see @Joe's answer above since you are looking to move sheets inside the same workbook, not from one workbook to another: `...
While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=openfiles(x))
    wb.Sheets().Move After:=wb.Sheets (ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
    x = x + 1
Wend
...`

Comment: I just ran it, no issues in my Excel 2010. Try closing and reopening Excel. Caveat: you are moving your sheets in place, since you are selecting them all and moving them after the last one, so try moving just one sheet. Try using `wb.Sheets(1).Move After:= wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)`.

Comment: Thank You for replying as Joe said Addin was being referred as ThisWorkbook so I declared a variable but it is opening sheets of one file only. I am trying to open other files sheets into my current file.
    Dim crntfile As Workbook
    Set crntfile = ActiveWorkbook
    While x <= UBound(openfiles)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=openfiles(x)
        Sheets().Move After:=crntfile.Sheets(crntfile.Sheets.Count)
        x = x + 1
    Wend
Also while running Add-In in a new file it's giving error: Method 'Sheets' of object '_Workbook' failed

Comment: Then put `Dim wa As Workbook    Set wa = Application.ActiveWorkbook` before the loop, put `wb.Worksheets().Copy After:=wa.Sheets(wa.Sheets.Count)` inside the loop and make sure you have only your current spreadsheet with the add-in open when you start. That's all from my end.

Answer (score 0):

If your code is running in an add-in, `ThisWorkbook` refers to the add-in.  Instead you probably want to refer explicitly to the workbook you just opened.  Maybe something like:

```
Dim wkb As Workbook

While x <= UBound(openfiles)
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=openfiles(x))
    Sheets().Move After:=wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count)
    x = x + 1
Wend
```

Comment: You are right ThisWorkbook is referring to Add-In. The above code is opening all new files separately but I want all sheets from the file just into my current file. Any suggestion please.
Sorry but I am a beginner in VBA.